# Edit menu in umbraco site

Tags: umbraco

I need to support a site made using umbraco. am a total newbie in umbraco. let me explain my scenario. I have left have menu which is used to navigate to different pages. Now i need to change one menu item to navigate to a different page. How is this posible?

It is using macro to create the main menu. The master page shows it has macro DisplayMainMenu. This macro uses XSLT file DisplayMainMenu. Am attaching the xslt code herewith:

```
<div id="main_navigation" class="jqueryslidemenu unitPng">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <xsl:for-each select="$pagesNodeSet">
      <xsl:sort select="./@sortOrder" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
      <li>
        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(./@id)}"><xsl:value-of select="./title"/></a>
        <xsl:if test="count(./*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1' and string(includeInMainNavigation) = '1']) &gt; 0">
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <xsl:for-each select="./*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1' and string(includeInMainNavigation) = '1']">
              <xsl:sort select="./@sortOrder" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
              <li><a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(./@id)}"><xsl:value-of select="./title"/></a></li>               
            </xsl:for-each>
          </ul>
        </xsl:if>
      </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Some code part couldnot be included due to some issues with formatting.

Comment: Not really enough info here to work with. How is this menu generated? Is it using a macro? If so can you post the macro code (xslt or razor)?

Comment: I shall edit my post with the xslt code.

Answer (score 1):

Your xslt is dynamically creating the menu based on your site layout as defined in the content section of the umbraco dashboard. Therefore you can't "change a menu item to point to a different page" as such. What you can do is change you site structure to reflect what you want by adding new pages, moving existing pages or removing unwanted pages.

If you want to add a static page link you can do this by adding it to your xslt above (in the same way the 'Home' link has been added) but you will need to ensure that is sits outside the `xslt:for-each` loop unless you want to get into some complex xslt coding.

Essentially, what the above code is doing is creating an unorderd list with the first list item statically added for the home page. It is then looping each of the child pages and adding a link. Then for each child page ,if it has visible child pages (by ensuring they are not supposed to be hidden and should be included in the main navigation using their umbracoNaviHide and includeInMainNavigation properties), it is looping over each of them and displaying a link.